# regex remove carriage return on group to no space

Tags: regex

I am trying to match tag "broken" or not complete (many tag) with a carriage for remove a carriage return on group

from this data:

```
    <gcusf><gcusfname>SEND-SU-01</gcusfname>
<gcusfvalue>'||"TO CHECK AUTOMATIC DISCART FOR USER"'</gc
usfvalue>
    </gcusf>
    <gcrvalf>YYMMDD</gcrvalf><gcrvalt>YYMMDD</gcrvalt>
<gcrundesc>'MY DESC YYMMDD -L2,-L4,-L5 OF WEEK'</gcrunde
sc><gcrunrule>E</gcrunrule><gcrtype>N</gcrtype><gcriat>2300</gcriat>
```

to this i'm try a regex ends with </ with letters and a new line

https://regex101.com/r/DkLdgz/1

```
<\/[a-z]+\s*\r?\n
```

with this match

```
</gc
</gcrunde
```

to this i'm try a regex starts with letters and ends in >

https://regex101.com/r/u9fmRL/1

```
^[a-z]+>
```

with this match

```
sc>
usfvalue>
```

and with this one group for match

https://regex101.com/r/Z1JI0P/1

```
(<\/[a-z]+\s*\r?\n+^[a-z]+>)
```

```
</gc
usfvalue>
```

```
</gcrunde
sc>
```

how to remove on group a carriage return?

from this

```
</gc
usfvalue>

</gcrunde
sc>
```

to this:

```
</gcusfvalue>
</gcrundesc>
```

thanks

Comment: You can change it into a lookahead, and then replace with group 1 `(<\/[a-z]+)\s*\r?\n(?=[a-z]+>)` See https://regex101.com/r/q9QQMh/1

Comment: Unless you have any line breaks in your data, it might be easier to strip them all and apply formatting with xmllint or some tool like this.

Comment: @The fourth bird thanks, works fine, i'm found another case with only < and </ for each i make other regex taking inspiration from yours : for only </ this: (<\/+)\s*\r?\n(?=[a-z]+>) and for only < this:  (<+)\s*\r?\n maybe can do everything in just one regex but the file is very large and I prefer to check everything. thanks for answer.

Comment: @italo_pm Why don't you make the `/` optional? `(<\/?)\s*\r?\n(?=[a-z][^<>]*>)` https://regex101.com/r/gdPb1H/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I had also handled that case with a different regex but it is not completed like yours, but if I wanted to do everything with just one regex, I tried to do it with this one but it doesn't match in cases when the line that returns begins with a > and /text> symbols. i'm rename tag with name cases(1-5) please see close tag on case3 and case4 https://regex101.com/r/uBFixL/1 thanks.

Comment: @italo_pm What tool / language are you using to do this? Can there always occur at most 1 newline in the tags that you want to fix?

Comment: @italo_pm Perhaps you could do it like this `\s*\r?\n(?=[^<>]*>)` https://regex101.com/r/YvKCdX/1 Or like this if an infinite quantifier in a lookbehind is supported `(?<=<\/[^>]*)\s*\r?\n(?=[^<>]*>)` https://regex101.com/r/Tk79OD/1 Or match at least a char a-z within the closing tag, and then using code like Python for example to remove the newlines from the match `<\/[^<>]*[a-z][^<>]*>` https://regex101.com/r/rsHrGR/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird i'm use tool Editpad Lite 8 and this regex \s*\r?\n(?=[^<>]*>) works perfect, now match all 5 case. just as additional information the file is created by extract with only 80 columns and then wrapping on a new line. thank you.

Comment: @italo_pm Did the last regex solve your issue?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, i'm solve with the last regex, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use match optional whitespace characters followed by a newline, and then assert a `>` character to the right:

```
\s*\n(?=[^<>]*>)
```

The pattern in parts:

- `\s*` Match optional whitespace characters
- `\n` Match a newline
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `[^<>]*>` Match 0+ times a character other than `<` or `>` and then match `>`
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aIDBMa/1)